# How can I push sub-nav ul out of main-nav ul?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, html-lists

I have a CMS-generated main-nav menu with one sub-menu. Both menus are standard ul tags with a class of “navCMSListMenuUL” which is then styled in my CSS accordingly. The issue is that on a:hover, the container expands to accommodate the newly displayed sub-nav ul.

I would like for the sub-nav to go outside of the container and flow at a higher z-index than any elements beneath the container. There are a couple of other things that I would like to clean up in this nav, but those are ancillary to the sub-nav flow. I have created a reduced test-case in Codepen @ http://codepen.io/patrickTheWizard/pen/ZGWKYX .

```
<nav class="navigation">
<ul id="menuElem" class="navCMSListMenuUL">
    <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
        <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
        <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
        <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Calendar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navCMSListMenuHighlightedLI noseparator">
        <a class="navCMSListMenuLinkHighlighted" href="#">Members</a>
        <ul class="navCMSListMenuUL">
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Become a Member</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Board Meetings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Committees</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Current Members</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Member Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navCMSListMenuLI noseparator">
                <a class="navCMSListMenuLink" href="#">Statistics &amp; Data</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

```
/* #01-Header/Nav# */
nav.navigation {
  clear: both;
  /* background-color: #3c3c3c; */
  overflow: visible;
  /* padding: 15px; */
  /* border-top: 6px solid #2a8cec; */
  /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
}

ul#menuElem {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  border-top: 6px solid #2a8cec;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul#menuElem li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 16px 0 15px 0;
}

ul#menuElem a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  margin: 15px 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

ul#menuElem a:hover {
  background-color: #2a8cec;
}

ul#menuElem li ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

ul#menuElem li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul#menuElem ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you when doing menu-like code, you are going to have styles that override each other (multiple nested UL, LI and A).

It's good practice to include the ">" element in your style sheets, which limits the scope of your query to direct children.

I have edited your code a bit, mainly by introducing that direct child rule (>). I also made the sub menu absolute positioned to it's parent, meaning you will not have the sub menu push your main menu to grow large.

[Here is your code pen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbdRgB)

And the code:

```
/* #01-Header/Nav# */
nav.navigation {
  clear: both;
  /* background-color: #3c3c3c; */
  overflow: visible;
  /* padding: 15px; */
  /* border-top: 6px solid #2a8cec; */
  /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
}

ul#menuElem {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  border-top: 6px solid #2a8cec;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul#menuElem > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px 0 15px 0;
}

ul#menuElem > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  margin: 15px 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

ul#menuElem > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #2a8cec;
}

ul#menuElem > li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

ul#menuElem > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul#menuElem > li:hover > ul > li{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;
}

ul#menuElem > li:hover > ul > li > a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

ul#menuElem > li:hover > ul > li:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

ul#menuElem > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```